# MEAN / Angular 4: Trouble displaying data in select

Tags: javascript, angular

(Edit: corrected wrong bracket)
(Edit: Changed the HTML code to use `*ngFor`)

I am new (and struggling) with Angular and the MEAN stack, so please be patient.
I am having problems displaying the data i get from MongoDB in my HTML `<select>.`

my service:

```
getLacadorByClubeId(idClube){
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
     let ep = this.authService.prepEndpoint('lacador/listByClubeId');

     //important: returning the res with a Map. Maybe the problem is here?
     return this.http.get(ep,{headers: headers, params: {idClube: idClube}})
       .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.clubesdelacoService.getClubesdelaco().subscribe((clubesdelaco) => {
      this.Clubedelaco = clubesdelaco;
      console.log(clubesdelaco);
};
```

my HTML:

```
        <div *ngIf="!isView" class="controls col-md-8 ">
            <select name="clube"  id="repeatSelect" class="input-md form-control" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <option *ngFor="let clube of this.Clubedelaco" [ngValue]="clube._id">{{clube.name}}</option>
                </select>
                <option ng-repeat="clube in this.Clubedelaco" value="{{clube._id}}">{{clube.name}}</option>
            </select>
         </div>
```

That results in messages on the browser CONSOLE:

[Image of Browser console, please note that the data seems to be inside an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MSUT.jpg)

And nothing in shown in the combobox :(

So, my view SUPPOSEDLY is receiving the data, but I am failing to show it.
My question is, what is the problem?
Wrong use of the `<select>` ? Need to transform the object into array? If so, how?

Comment: You are mixing angularjs and angular(what you call angular 4). Also you have a typo in ngOnInit. the closing bracket should be a curly brace.

Comment: There is NO `ng-repeat` and no `ng-options` in Angular 2+

Comment: Please tag questions **only** related to the **specific part of the problem** you currently have. Broad tags like "mean stack" are of little real use, and when your question is about the "angular" part it also does not require tagging every tech in your stack. It's about the "question" and not your tech stack or desired exposure.

Comment: Changed the HTML to **`<option *ngFor="let clube of this.Clubedelaco" [ngValue]="clube._id">{{clube.name}}</option>`** by suggestion of @Alexander Staroselsky.

Comment: See the updated answer, you should be able to iterate over the `clubesdelacolist` object nested within the returned objected using `*ngFor="let clube of Clubedelaco.clubesdelacolist"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate the `<select>` you can use `*ngFor`. There is no `ng-options` or `ng-repeat` in Angular 2+. You can use `[ngValue]="someExpression"` to set the `value` attribute of each `<option>` to a given property on the `clube` data object, in your case it looks like that would be the `_id` property.

This assumes that `Clubedelaco` is an array of objects.

```
<div *ngIf="someCondition">
  <select name="clube">
    <option *ngFor="let clube of Clubedelaco.clubesdelacolist" [ngValue]="clube._id">{{clube.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecwf95?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) in action. It's been set up to demonstrate/simulate async setting `Clubedelaco` in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

To bind the data as part of a form you'll need to either use [Template Driven Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) or [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

To avoid using nested objects, you can utilize the RxJS `map()` operator to transform the result from your http get call. You could for example, just return the inner array. It would look something like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

// instead of any, you'd ideally want to make a class/interface to represent the clube object
getLacadorByClubeId(idClube): Observable<any[]> {
  // setting headers as before

  return this.http.get(ep,{headers: headers, params: {idClube: idClube}})
    .map(res => res.json())
    // additional map() chained on
    // emit the clubesdelacolist array value instead of original object
    // you can do more formatting/projection here if needed
    .map(res => res['clubesdelacolist']) as Observable<any[]>;
}
```

Then in your component:

```
@Component({})
export class SomeComponent {
  // create a class or interface to represent the clube objects and their properties
  Clubedelaco: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clubesdelacoService.getClubesdelaco()
      // clubesdelaco comes in as an array now
      .subscribe((clubesdelaco) => {
        this.Clubedelaco = clubesdelaco;
        console.log(clubesdelaco);
      };
}
```

This would allow you to do the following in the HTML:

```
<option *ngFor="let clube of Clubedelaco" [ngValue]="clube._id">{{clube.name}}</option>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input! I changed the code accordingly, and now I have the console error: Error: 

'Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff '

I need to change the content of 'this.Clubedelaco'?

Comment: Yes, `Clubedelaco`/`this.Clubedelaco` would need to be an array. Or if it's just a single object, you would need need to use something like `map()` to turn it into an array or iterable object. Can you please add a snippet of how `clubesdelaco` is coming out in `console.log()`? Without knowing the structure, it is difficult to fully help.

Comment: I see the structure now from your image, I've updated my answer. It looks like the array is in an inner object of `clubesdelacolist`? Try `*ngFor="let clube of Clubedelaco.clubesdelacolist"`. Remember you can use {{ Clubedelaco | json }} to see the formatted data if you need in the template. I've also updated the answer to match the data structure.

Comment: Your suggestion solved the problem, thanks a lot for this! I was stuck with this problems for hours :/   Apparently all my services are returning this Object of arrays, instead of a simple Array (which is what I would prefer)

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Keep in mind you can use `map()` prior to the `subscribe()` to transform the emit values from the Observable (http request) to avoid having to deal with nested objects.

Comment: How can I use the map() to do that? You mean in the component ? Can you demonstrate?

Comment: I've updated the example to show using `map()` (an additional map) to target the `clubesdelacolist` property of the response from server. I'd highly recommend to create an interface or class to represent each `clube` object. That way you can use that object/interface instead of `any` and take advantage of stronger typing and autocomplete in your IDE. The goal in this example would be just to return an Observable of an array, rather than the object with the inner nested property. In the end the result is the same. Hope that helps!